# Is there a way to set the whole Neopixel Led strip on one color at one time with the Library from jgarff

Tags: python, adafruit, neopixel

I was wondering if there is a way to set the whole WS2812B Led strip on one color at once with the [library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x) from Jgarff?

I know i could use this code:

```
    while True:
        for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
            strip.setPixelColor(i, (0, 255, 0))
            strip.show()
```

But i have 864 Led's so it takes the Raspberry Pi 30 seconds to set all the Leds on the given color.

So I searched for a command like strip.fill or something like that and i didnt find anything. So is there a command or a fix for the for loop?

I'm thankfull for any input.

example1

```
        for i in range(0, strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, (0, 255, 0))
        strip.show()
```

Comment: Is the `strip.show()` line part of the loop, or not?  We can't tell because you failed to accurately preserve your indentation when pasting the code here.

Comment: Yeah, sorry the strip.setPixelColor(i, color) and the strip.show() are part of the for loop i forgot the tab.

Comment: Well, get it out of the loop then!  That's the exact opposite of the "all at once" behavior you want.

Comment: How do I do that. Could you please give me a sample. Im new to programming.

Comment: Just unindent that line so it lines up with the `for` statement.

Comment: Like in the example1 on the question?

Comment: I put the strip.begin now outside the for loop and now it works.